# Number Format Exception in Groovy

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui, jsonslurper

I am trying to compare the Sales Tax Rate of 6.75 against my expected value of 6.75 which is in string format. I wrote the below lines of Groovy code to achieve this, but I am getting Number Format Exception and I could not figure out where the problem is

**Groovy Code**

```
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def parsedResponseJson=jsonSlurper.parseText(context.expand('${StandardFinance#Response}'))
def actualSalesTaxRate = parsedResponseJson.CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse.StandardFinanceResponse.Responses[0].StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse.paymentWithTaxes.financeItemizedTaxes.salesTax.taxParameters.rate
def actualSalesTaxRate = parsedResponseJson.CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse.StandardFinanceResponse.Responses[0].StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse.paymentWithTaxes.financeItemizedTaxes.salesTax.taxParameters.rate
log.info actualSalesTaxRate.size()
actualSalesTaxRate = Float.parseFloat(actualSalesTaxRate)
def expectedSalesTaxRate = "6.75"
log.info expectedSalesTaxRate.size()
expectedSalesTaxRate = Float.parseFloat(expectedSalesTaxRate)
assert expectedSalesTaxRate.toString() == actualSalesTaxRate.toString(),"FAIL --- Sales Tax Rate is different"
```

**JSON Response**

```
{
"CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse": {
    "StandardFinanceResponse": {
        "Responses": [{
            "StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse": {
                "class": ".APRNonCashCustomerQuote",
                "RequestID": "1",
                "term": "48",
                "financeSourceId": "F000CE",
                "paymentWithTaxes": {
                    "class": ".FinancePaymentWithTaxes",
                    "amountFinanced": "34523.48",
                    "monthlyPayment": "782.60",
                    "monthlyPaymentWithoutDealerAddOns": 782.6,
                    "financeItemizedTaxes": {
                        "salesTax": {
                            "taxParameters": {
                                "rate": "6.75"
                            },
                            "salesTaxAmount": "2322.61"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to convert it to number as the value in the response is string.

- define a test case level custom property say `EXPECTED_TAX_RATE` and provide the value as `6.75`.
- in the response, the `rate` is a string value.
- there is no need to create an additional Groovy Script test step in this particular case just to check/compare the value, remove step.
- instead, add `Script Assertion` for the rest request test step itself with above code.
- however, there is small change need to read the response.

Here is the complete `Script Assertion`

```
//Check the response is received
assert context.response, 'Response is empty or null'

//Read test case property for expected value as string; this way there is no need to edit the assertion; just change the property value
def expectedTaxRate = context.expand('${#TestCase#EXPECTED_TAX_RATE}')

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(context.response)

def actualTaxRate = json.CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse.StandardFinanceResponse.Responses[0].StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse.paymentWithTaxes.financeItemizedTaxes.salesTax.taxParameters.rate
log.info "Actual tax rate $actualSalesTaxRate"

//Now compare expected and actual
assert actualTaxRate == expectedTaxRate, 'Both tax rates are not matching'
```

You may have question such as "Leave about string values. How to compare with Numbers. For example `monthlyPaymentWithoutDealerAddOns` is having number not string. How to deal with it?"

Here when a test case level custom property is defined as `EXPECTED_MONTHLY_PATYMENT` and value as `782.6`.

Like it is already mentioned the above can be read in `Script Assertion` as below

```
def expectedMonthlyPayment = context.expand('${#TestCase#EXPECTED_MONTHLY_PATYMENT}') //but this is string
```

You can read actual value as:

```
def actualPayment = json.CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse.StandardFinanceResponse.Responses[0].StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse.paymentWithTaxes.monthlyPaymentWithoutDealerAddOns
log.info actualPayment.class.name //this shows the data type
```

Now *expectedPayment* needs to be converted to *actualPayment*'s type

```
def actualPayment = json.CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse.StandardFinanceResponse.Responses[0].StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse.paymentWithTaxes.monthlyPaymentWithoutDealerAddOns
log.info actualPayment.class.name //this shows the data type
def expectedPayment = context.expand('${#TestCase#EXPECTED_MONTHLY_PATYMENT}') as BigDecimal
assert actualPayment == actualPayment
```

Comment: Alternatively, `actualPayment` can also be converted to string and compare.

Comment: Srinivasan, have you got chance to try the solution?

Comment: Hi Rao, Sorry I went busy with manual project and could not try your solution on time. There was a mistake in my code logic where I was trying to convert an empty string into decimal which caused the Number Format Exception. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Given this JSON (similar to the full one provided, but with closing syntax):

```
def s = '''
{"CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse": {"StandardFinanceResponse": {
   "Responses": [   {   
      "StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse":       {   
         "class": ".APRNonCashCustomerQuote",
         "RequestID": "1",
         "term": "48",
         "financeSourceId": "F000CE",
         "paymentWithTaxes":          {   
            "class": ".FinancePaymentWithTaxes",
            "amountFinanced": "34523.48",
            "monthlyPayment": "782.60",
            "monthlyPaymentWithoutDealerAddOns": 782.6,
            "financeItemizedTaxes":             {   
               "salesTax":                {   
                  "taxParameters": {"rate": "6.75"},
                      "salesTaxAmount": "2322.61"
}}}}}]}}}
'''
```

Consider this code:

```
def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(s)
def response = json.CustomerQuoteFinanceResponse
                   .StandardFinanceResponse
                   .Responses[0]

assert 6.75 == response.StandardPaymentEngineFinanceResponse
                       .paymentWithTaxes
                       .financeItemizedTaxes
                       .salesTax
                       .taxParameters
                       .rate as Float
```